# Power BI - Created a button but the option to navigate to another page missing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a button in Power BI, but when I select on the "Action" option, the ability to navigate to another page is not an option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tell something more. Edit your question and add screenshot from "Format Button"+ show how you add this button.

Comment: You will get the option "Page Navigation" under action.

Comment: I am using an older version of Power BI Desktop. I was using the January 2020 version, and the Page Navigation option wasn't available until March 2020. Problem solved.

Comment: Okay, Power bi platform is still new project from Microsoft side. So their is monthly releases and power bi tenet updates. They are adding new features along with ideas of members. Its better to update your dashboard and go through release note .

Answer (score 3):

In here you able to add action for your button,

[image]